# Public dataset for spanish news articles with title and content

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp

I am wondering if there are any public datasets of news in SPANISH similar to [this dataset](http://research.signalmedia.co/newsir16/signal-dataset.html).
Which consists mostly of ENGLISH news. There is a similar question already answered [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23323/public-dataset-for-news-articles-with-their-associated-categories).
However, I require the news to be in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a labeled dataset of news written in Spanish](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~voyanede/cc5213/datasets/ciperchile_21.12.2018/)

This dataset contains 3.089 articles written in spanish with tags and authors, extracted this month.